# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried a PHP script but it always gives me an error. I have added the script into my .htaccess to auto-load everytime.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/fantasycf/public/proxycheck.php
```

No matter what I try, I receive this error:

```
Sat Jan 07 06:40:04.756520 2017] [php7:error] [pid 5269] [client 187.57.43.66:23391] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare checkProxy() (previously declared in /var/my/private/directory/proxycheck.php:11) in /var/my/private/directory/proxycheck.php on line 11, referer: http://test.com/test.html
```

My PHP script is the following:

```
    <?php
/*
* A PHP function that interacts with http://getIPIntel.net to look up an IP address
* returns TRUE if the IP returns a value greater than $banOnProability,
* FALSE otherwise, including errors
* HTTP error codes are NOT explicitly implemented here
* This should be used as a guide, be sure to edit and test it before using it in production
* MIT License
*/
//function requires curl
function checkProxy($ip){
    $contactEmail="admin@mysite.com"; //you must change this to your own email address
    $timeout=5; //by default, wait no longer than 5 secs for a response
    $banOnProbability=0.99; //if getIPIntel returns a value higher than this, function returns true, set to 0.99 by default

    //init and set cURL options
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    //if you're using custom flags (like flags=m), change the URL below
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://check.getipintel.net/check.php?ip=$ip&contact=$contactEmail");
    $response=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);


    if ($response > $banOnProbability) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($response < 0 || strcmp($response, "") == 0 ) {
            //The server returned an error, you might want to do something
            //like write to a log file or email yourself
            //This could be true due to an invalid input or you've exceeded
            //the number of allowed queries. Figure out why this is happening
            //because you aren't protected by the system anymore
            //Leaving this section blank is dangerous because you assume
            //that you're still protected, which is incorrect
            //and you might think GetIPIntel isn't accurate anymore
            //which is also incorrect.
            //failure to implement error handling is bad for the both of us
        }
        return false;
    }
}
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (checkProxy($ip)) {
    /* A proxy has been detected based on your criteria
     * Do whatever you want to here
     */
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=google.com">';    
    exit;
}

?>
```

I hope you can help.

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you using `require` or `include` twice?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when using `require` or `include` twice. This can be solved by finding all the instances of `include` and `require` that use that file and make sure you change it using:

```
require_once "filename";
```

The alternate way is to check if the function is already declared, if so, don't redeclare. You can do it by using `function_exists()`:

```
if (!function_exists("checkProxy")) {
  function checkProxy($ip) {
    // rest of function code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your function declaration inside if statement

```
if(!function_exists('checkProxy'))
{
    /*
* A PHP function that interacts with http://getIPIntel.net to look up an IP address
* returns TRUE if the IP returns a value greater than $banOnProability,
* FALSE otherwise, including errors
* HTTP error codes are NOT explicitly implemented here
* This should be used as a guide, be sure to edit and test it before using it in production
* MIT License
*/
//function requires curl
function checkProxy($ip){
    $contactEmail="admin@mysite.com"; //you must change this to your own email address
    $timeout=5; //by default, wait no longer than 5 secs for a response
    $banOnProbability=0.99; //if getIPIntel returns a value higher than this, function returns true, set to 0.99 by default

    //init and set cURL options
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    //if you're using custom flags (like flags=m), change the URL below
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://check.getipintel.net/check.php?ip=$ip&contact=$contactEmail");
    $response=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);


    if ($response > $banOnProbability) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if ($response < 0 || strcmp($response, "") == 0 ) {
            //The server returned an error, you might want to do something
            //like write to a log file or email yourself
            //This could be true due to an invalid input or you've exceeded
            //the number of allowed queries. Figure out why this is happening
            //because you aren't protected by the system anymore
            //Leaving this section blank is dangerous because you assume
            //that you're still protected, which is incorrect
            //and you might think GetIPIntel isn't accurate anymore
            //which is also incorrect.
            //failure to implement error handling is bad for the both of us
        }
        return false;
    }
}
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (checkProxy($ip)) {
    /* A proxy has been detected based on your criteria
     * Do whatever you want to here
     */
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=google.com">';    
    exit;
}

}
```